# Why is Url.RouteUrl not generating address for a route that has contraint in it

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have an action in my controller that has a route constraint to make sure an ID is passed in. When this constraint is in the route the `@Url.RouteUrl()` does not generate a URL for the route, if I remove the constraint the URL is generated with no issues. Is this a bug in .Net 5 or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried the following to generate the URL:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("AboutVersion")
@Url.RouteUrl("AboutVersion", new { id = 1 })
@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home")
@Url.Action("AboutVersion")
@Url.Action("AboutVersion", new { id = 1 })
```

Action:

```
    [Route("About/{Version:int}", Name = "AboutVersion")]
    public JsonResult AboutVersion(byte VersionID)
    {
        var VersionNotes = _DbContext.ReleaseNotes
                                     .Where(rn => rn.ReleaseVersionID == VersionID)
                                     .Select(rn => rn.Note)
                                     .ToList();

        return Json(VersionNotes);
    }
```

Edit:
This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#SelectedVersionID').change(function ()
        {
            var SelectedVersionID = $(this).val();
            var ReleaseNotesSection = $('#ReleaseNotes');

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home", new { VersionID = 1 })',
                data: { 'VersionID': SelectedVersionID },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert('@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home")');
                    ReleaseNotesSection.html('');

                    $.each(data, function (note)
                    {
                        ReleaseNotesSection.append($('<li></li>').html(note));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Produces this output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#SelectedVersionID').change(function ()
        {
            var SelectedVersionID = $(this).val();
            var ReleaseNotesSection = $('#ReleaseNotes');

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '',
                data: { 'VersionID': SelectedVersionID },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert('');
                    ReleaseNotesSection.html('');

                    $.each(data, function (note)
                    {
                        ReleaseNotesSection.append($('<li></li>').html(note));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your attribute route definition, you say that the `VersoionID` should be of `int` type.

So this generate the correct url.

```
var v1= '@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home",new { VersionID =2})';
alert(v1);
```

But this will not

```
var v2 = '@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home")';
alert(v2);
```

So if you change your `VersionID` param type from `Int` to `Nullable Int`, It will work for both overloads of `Url.Action` we used above.

```
[Route("About/{VersionID:int?}", Name = "AboutVersion")]
public JsonResult AboutVersion(byte VersionID)
{
   // return something
}
```

You need to make sure that your action method parameter and the param you have in the url pattern in your attribute route definition should match. (*It did not in the code you posted in the question*)

Also, If you do not use the attribute route decorators, your code will work for both the overloads.

Comment: I just tyried `@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home", new { VersionID = 1 })` and that did not work.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? I double checked it and it worked for me. Are you sure you don't have any typo's in the param name ?

Comment: Are you in MVC6 on ASP.Net 5? I am copying and pasting my code exactly and do not see any miss typings.

Comment: Yes. Verified in MVC 6.

Comment: See my edit. That is the exact code I am running right now and the output. I have not changed the code for the action in the controller.

Comment: in your controller action, your param name in the route definition is not same as `VersionID`. Can you try to change it and see ? See my edit in the answer.

Comment: That was the problem. Now `@Url.RouteUrl("AboutVersion", new { VersionID = 1 })` and `@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home", new { VersionID = 1 })` work.

Comment: Because the `@UrlAction` is expecting to have the ID in it do you know how I would put a dynamic ID into it from my JavaScript?

Comment: Change the type to `int?` in the route definition and then `'@Url.Action("AboutVersion", "Home")'` will give you the url to the action method. and set that to a js variable and add the querystring values using your js variables by simply appending to it.